# How to handle a non usable TODO case in a script?

Tags: error-handling

What's the proper handling for a part of a script that is a non usable TODO case? Should throw an exception, a false assertion, crash the script or something else?

By non-usable I mean it is not implemented, so that part of the script just does nothing yet.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you have a concrete example? Why would you check in incomplete code?

Comment: Not production environment, in case a part of the script is predicted but not implemented yet, if it gets reached it will most likely cause an unexpected result, so instead of that I would like to report with a generic todo message, I feel like it should be a false assertion, but I am not sure, since a false assertion is supposed to be a part of a script that should never be reached in the design.

Comment: C# will let you [`throw new NotImplementedException("your message here");`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82w4z3k8(v=vs.110).aspx).  Are you looking for something similar for your scripting language?

Comment: @DanPichelman yes, I am programming in PHP

Comment: @DanPichelman so I understand exceptions are the general solution, then I can even create my own exception class for handling this kind of situation, or use a predefined language class for that matter, now that I dig into exceptions and think a little deeper about them again, it actually seems perfectly logical to me, I believe that's the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should treat the case as broken and fix it.  The whole point of leaving a todo in code is to admit to the next programmer, "I meant to fix this but apparently you got here before I did."

You have to design a working solution.  Don't sit there trying to divine wisdom from a comment left by someone who didn't complete this idea.  Figure out what the program needs to do and make it do that.

The point of a todo isn't to hold your place.  It's to admit you never finished proving this stuff works.

Comment: What if I forget about the TODO concept, and just create an exception class called NotImplementedException like in C#? I say that because actually my case is specifically just a not implemented functionality that is predicted (for example in a digital signature class, one of many algorithms to be implemented).

Comment: @mikl Always consider the null object pattern before you litter your code with landmines.  Last thing I want to see on an object is things I can't use.  Things I can use that do nothing aren't so bad so long as doing nothing isn't failing quietly.  I tell my Dog to bark I want it to bark. I tell my sofa to bark I don't want a hole to open in the universe. A sofa that doesn't bark is what I expect.  I don't expect the sofa to explain to me why it can't talk.   I don't want to have to know what I'm talking to to be sure I can ask it to bark.  Whatever you do, don't make me ask to find out.